# SQLAlchemy how can I append a column that depends on other columns of the same model

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have the model

```
class Coords(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    latitude = db.Column(db.Float)
    longitude = db.Column(db.Float)
```

I want to query this table with an added column defined as the sum of latitude and longitude times some arbitrary factor.

In other words, what I'm expecting is

```
>>>arbitrary_factor = 10
>>>(db.session.query(Coords)...).__dict__
{latitude : 10, longitude :20, third_col : 300 }
```

how can I do this using flask-SQLAlchemy?

Comment: How arbitrary is the arbitrary factor?  Does it apply to all instances, could there be a different factor for each instance?  What if latitude or longitude are updated?

Comment: In my app, this factor comes from the request body, so the factor would be only known at the time of the query.

Comment: Is it ever necessary to recover the factor, or recompute the value, or is it unchanging once created?

Comment: the factor is from the request body, so it is unchanged once created.